# Is $X=(n^2)^\infty_n$ unbounded?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read the section about numerical sequencies.

There is stated (assuming $X \subset R$):

> X is "bounded below" if and only if $\exists m \in R: \forall x \in X$ $x \geq m$ (1)

> X is "bounded" if and only if $\exists m,M \in R: \forall x \in X$ $m  \leq x \leq M$, i.e. $X \subset  [m,M] (2)$.

> Often $[m,M]$ is considered symmetrically to x=0, so X is "bounded" if and only if $\exists K \in R, K>0: \forall x \in X$ $|x| \leq K (3)$

> Using the negation of the statement, we have: X is "unbounded" if and only if $\forall K>0:\exists x_k \in X: |x_k|>K (4)$

> Example: Set $A=(n^2)^\infty_n$ is **unbounded**, because $\forall K>0$ can be found $n_k=[\sqrt{k}]+1$ *(remark: brackets probably mean floor)*, that $|n^2_k|=n^2_k=k+1+2\sqrt{k}>k (5) $* (remark: literally how it is written, i.e. equation then inequality; also $k$ is not defined, it just appears)*

Do I understand correctly, that (4) violates (1) the way (5) is true due to (4) and at the same time false due to (1)?

Is (5) unbounded or bounded below? Also what proof of (5) is about at all? I do not understand why there is $+1$ in $[\sqrt{1}]+1$, for example.

---

I think I found where is the problem: in $(3)$ author starts to consider case, when $M-m=0$, and all that comes after $(3)$ seems to be applied only to such case.

Comment: It's bounded below and unbounded. To be bounded it has to be bounded below and bounded above.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, any set bounded below is also unbounded?

Comment: For all $k > 0$ you want an $n_k$ that is strictly greater than $k$. If you choose $n_k=[\sqrt{k}]$ you can get $n_k=\sqrt{k}$ such as for $k=1$.

Comment: Yes, a set can be bounded below and unbounded. Think about $n^2$ for a second. The smallest possible value is $1$ so it's a lower bound. That means it's bounded below. However no matter how big a number you pick I can find $n^2$ that is larger. This means it's unbounded above, and therefore unbounded.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, okay, simply question: if set is bounded above and not bounded below, is it bounded? For example, set $(2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,...)$ is bounded?

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I think the right answer on the question above is: "depeding which definition of bounding set to choose", because definition $(3)$ is not equivalent to definition $(2)$, since according to $(3)$ set $(1,0,−1,−2,−3,...)$ is bounded, but according to $(2)$ not, because according to $(3)$ there is $K>0$, so any $|x|$ is less or equal to such $K$, while, according to $(2)$ there is $M$, so any $x$ is less or equal to such $M$, but there is no $m$, so any $x$ is higher or equal to it

Comment: @CyclotomicField, and I think, but can't currently proove, that since $(3)$
 just violates $(2)$, $(4)$, that is obtained as negation of $(3)$ is also wrong.

Comment: A set is bounded if and only if it is bounded below and also bounded above. As a consequence, if a set is bounded below but not bounded above then it is unbounded.

Comment: The set $\{2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,\dots\}$ is not bounded because there is no $m$ such that $x \geq m$ for all $x$. It is bounded above by $2$ or any larger number but it's not bounded below.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, probably I confused. Need some time to think

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv these definitions should match your intuition. The sequence $(1,-1,1,-1,1,\dots )$ is bounded with $m=-1$ and $M=1$. The sequence $(1,2,3,4,\dots )$ is bounded below by $m=1$ but unbounded above so it's unbounded. The sequences $(-1,-2,-3,\dots )$ is bounded above by $-1$ but unbounded below so it's unbounded. The sequence $(1,-2,3,-4,5,\dots )$ is unbounded above and unbounded below, so it is unbounded.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I was actually generally right, was a bit confused when providing an example with a set. I needed to provide $(1,0,-1,-2)$ finite set, that is not bounded according $(3)$ and at the same time is bounded according to $(2)$. I delete my post now I just rewrite it

Comment: @CyclotomicField, although, no, I am wrong - $(1,0,-1,-2)$ is bounded according to $(3)$ as well as according to $(2)$, since there is a number $2$, so absolute value of every element is less or equal that number. However, I think, usage of absolute value is still pretty confusing, and of course using absolute value boundness can be determined qualitively and countively not in all cases (only when $m$ and $M$ are equal and have different signs)

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv the absolute value is often used simply to state the lower and upper cases in the same expression. For example if for some $\epsilon > 0$ we have $x - \epsilon < y < x + \epsilon$ you can instead write $\|y-x\| < \epsilon$. While at first it seems merely notational it can often be used to simplify some arguments and allows us to generalize to other norms.